# Переопределение ScrollView

Tags: android, java

имеется ImageView внутри ScrollView. необходимо что-то нарисовать пальцем. назначил слушатель для ImageView , но рисование не работает. Выяснилось что при рисовании горизонтальной линии на ImageView всё хорошо, но при вертикальной линии рисование блокируется.  как я понял это из-за ScrollView. Пытался переопределить метод onTouchEvent в ScrollView и возвращать false всё время но это не помогло. как мне быть ? как заставить ScrollView игнорировать  onTouchEvent ? 
p.s. ScrollView в данном приложении обязателен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

решил проблему переопределив метод onInterceptTouchEvent в ScrollView